# select 2 different count in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, count, sql-server-2012

I need to select top 20000 from my table that has several columns (number,color etc...) and i need to get the count of the red and the count of the blue from these 20000 in one query.

I know i can get what i want if i insert the top 20000 in a temp table and then select count of the red from the temp table and then select count of the blue from the temp table, but i need to do it in one query.

i tried the below but it gives me the count for every number, i need the total..

```
SELECT  top 20000 [number], count(color)
FROM [profile]
group by number
having color='red'
```

output:

### color | count

### red | 15000

### blue | 5000

Comment: Show us your expected output and its format.

Comment: @wewesthemenace you can find updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested query:

```
select inner.color, count(*) from 
(select top 20000 [number], color from [profile]) inner
group by inner.color
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `iif` :

```
select  top 20000 [number]
     , sum(iif([color] = 'red', 1, 0) as red_count
     , sum(iif([color] = 'blue', 1, 0) as blue_count
from [profile]
group by [number]
```

or `case`:

```
select  top 20000 [number]
     , sum(case when [color] = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) as red_count
     , sum(case when [color] = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) as blue_count
from [profile]
group by [number]
```

**Edit**. After you've updated your question, I guess your query should look like this:

```
select t.[color]
     , count(t.[color])
from (select  top 20000 [color] from [profile]) t
group by t.[color]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  top 20000 [number], count(color) as count_total, 
        sum(case when color='red' then 1 else 0 end) as count_red, 
        sum(case when color='blue' then 1 else 0 end) as count_blue
FROM [profile]
group by number
```